# Manipulating Excel files using VB8

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

My script is pulling some information (filename, date, &c) from a server that contains only (nearly) identical excel files generated by a separate application whenever it is used. The goal is to find out who is using the tool and how often.

I need help with two things: extracting info from within the excel file, and appending the results to the SAME excel file each time it's run instead of creating a new file each time.

Here is what I have...

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Imports System Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'declare excel objects
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer = 2


    'I know this is the problem area...
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = " File Name "
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2) = " Date Created  "

    'this should be cell B1
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 3) = " Requestor   "

    'this should be cell B21
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 4) = " Lead Type"


    'get to directory
    For Each strFolder As String In _
        My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("Z:\\...")

        'get file names
        Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo
        infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(strFolder)


        'write to excel worksheet
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1) = strFolder
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 2) = infoReader.CreationTime


        i += 1


    Next
    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\...")


    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()


    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    MsgBox("Excel file created , see file in c:\Documents")
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I've answered part of your question below (specifically, how to reference the current workbook/sheet instead of making a new one) but i'm a bit confused about your other question.

What do you mean by "This should be B1[21]" -- you appear to be writing column headers at the point of those comments ("Requestor" and "Lead Type") -- do you want those strings replaced by the contents of B1 and B21? Or do you want the contents of B1 and B21 to be filling each entry in that column? Or something else altogether? 

Could you rephrase that part of the question?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear on that... I would like those columns to be populated with data from cells B1 and B21

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new application and workbook, just use activeworkbook, e.g.
replace

```
'I know this is the problem area...
xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
```

with

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheetname")
```

where you replace sheetname with whatever the desired sheet name is.

Alternatively, you could just use `ActiveSheet`.